# C# Recieving NullReference error when using Where Contains

Tags: c#, lambda, filtering

When filtering a list using lambda where and contains, I get a NullReference error

```
var servers = _context.Servers.ToList();
servers = servers.Where(t => t.Technology.Contains(technology)).ToList();
```

But I get a this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in
>   ServerBuildApp.dll ServerBuildApp.Models.Servers.Technology.**get**
>   returned null.

The list of servers contains a 'Technology' property and it contains the string I am passing it, for example "BIZ"

Any ideas? Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: The title of question and the question itself has nothing to do with each other. Apparently you have at least one element in the list whose `Technology` property is null.

Comment: You are not exactly "filtering in place without creating a new list", more like "filtering and creating a new list, but assigning it to the same variable" - which is not a problem, just to keep things accurate. As for the error - it's not related, you just have some `Technology` properties with a value of `null` - check for it before you call a function on the value (e.g. `t.Technology?.Contains(technology)`)

Comment: I have updated the question and the content to represent the real problem, thanks for everyone's quick responses. Love this community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the t.Technology for null.

```
var servers = _context.Servers.ToList();
servers = servers.Where(t => t.Technology?.Contains(technology) is true).ToList();
```

You should check t.Technology for null and then check it contains.

Comment: Why not avoid making an extra list? `var servers = _context.Servers.Where(t => t.Technology?.Contains(technology)).ToList();`

Comment: t.Technology?.Contains(technology) return bool? but the where is Func<bool> that you should check the value

Comment: @MatthewWatson And you do need the `== true` check due to the nullable bool.

Comment: This is what I should have typed: `var servers = _context.Servers.Where(t => t.Technology?.Contains(technology) is true).ToList();` - this avoids making an extra unneccessary list. The main point here is to avoid making an extra list.

Comment: Lindexi's answer worked a treat. Thank you.

Comment: This helped me as well, thanks lindexi!